# How to define selection range of variable length?

Tags: r

Suppose I have a vector of 100 elements. How can I define the selection range based on another vector in the loop? The selection range for each iteration is different, e.g. 50, 30, 20 elements out of 100.

```r
vec = c(50, 30, 20)
for (i in seq_along(vec)) {
  # ???
}
```

As a result, these ranges are expected:

```
1:50
51:80
81:100
```

If the selection ranges are identical (for example 50, 50, 50), this is easy to do:

```r
vec = c(50, 50, 50)
for (i in seq_along(vec) - 1) {
  idx_min = i * 50 + 1
  idx_max = i * 50 + 50
  print(paste0(idx_min, ":", idx_max))
}
```

```
[1] "1:50"
[1] "51:100"
[1] "101:150"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cumsum` to the rescue:

```
to = cumsum(vec)
from = c(1L, head(to, -1L) + 1L)
for (i in seq_along(vec)) {
    slice = your_data[from[i] : to[i]]
    …
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use

```
v1 <- cumsum(vec)
Map(function(x, y) paste0(x, ":", y), c(1, v1[-length(v1)]+1), v1)
```

-output

```
[[1]]
[1] "1:50"

[[2]]
[1] "51:80"

[[3]]
[1] "81:100"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another base R option

```
> u <- cumsum(vec)

> v <- c(1, head(u, -1) + 1)

> paste0(v, ":", u)
[1] "1:50"   "51:80"  "81:100"
```

Comment: Nice option.  I was thinking `seq` first before I pasted